# laravel 5 html to pdf view issue

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, mpdf, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to put html and save it as pdf. however, it seems the content inside pdf not rendered well. I am using plugin from [maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export). Here is the code I've tried

Controller

```
Excel::create('test',function($file){
        $file->sheet('Sheet1', function ($sheet){

            $sheet->loadView('excel');
            $sheet->setAutoSize(true);
        });

    })->store('pdf',storage_path('uploaded-excel'));
```

View

```
<body>
    <p>test</p>
    <img src="images/hierarchy.png"/>
</body>
```

Result

[image]

But when I remove img tag, the size itself looks normal

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf plugin instead of using inbuilt function from maatwebsite